# Spring Boot Freemarker fails from 2.2.0 upgrade

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, freemarker

Upon upgrading the spring-boot-parent to `2.2.0.RELEASE`, my freemarker based Spring Boot Web application fails to properly serve requests.

I have a `@Controller` that serves `/hello` with `src/main/resources/templates/hello.ftl`.

```
@Controller
class HelloController() {
    @RequestMapping(value = ["/hello"])
    fun hello(): String {
        return "hello"
    }
}
```

upon request, it just lands on an error page saying `There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).`.

Error stacktrace doesn't say much. It just says `org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler: Resource not found`.

My `pom.xml` is basically as follows:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

It **worked perfectly fine up until upgrading to Spring Boot 2.2.0.RELEASE**.
What's the problem here?

- This is a self-answering question as per [rules](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) to prevent other poor souls from suffering like I did.

Comment: I was angry that I spent 1 hour going through DispatcherServlet and TemplateLoader decompiled sources to debug this only to find out I could've easily read the changelogs and saved myself the headache, so here's a self-answered question for anyone who might do the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is due to a breaking change in Spring Boot 2.2.0 with default freemarker suffixes.
Freemarker files should now end with `.ftlh` rather than `.ftl`.
`.ftlh` enables the HTML auto-escape feature.

The commit that changed this can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/7a9d1a1e342d4051318ec4f86c9b6d012aa9b373). It aims to fix [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/15131) that freemarker default settings should be safer, which is enabling automatic HTML escapes.

The full changelog for `2.2.0.RELEASE` that you should read before upgrading can be found [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes).