# 404 after spring-boot upgrade

Tags: spring-boot, migration

- I have been working on a migration spring-boot 1.5 to spring-boot 2.5. I am getting a 404   just traying to access the login page.
- Migration guide: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide
- usefull info: https://www.programmersought.com/article/26361415073/, https://developpaper.com/two-choices-after-the-webmvcconfigureradapter-class-is-abandoned/

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.base")
@ImportResource(locations = "classpath:reports/jasper-views.xml")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.base")
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = "com.base")
@EnableSpringDataWebSupport
@EnableWebSocket
public class GFLWeb {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GFLWeb.class, args);
    }
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class})
public class GFLMVCConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public static String[] FREE_ACCESS_PATHS = {
            "/ws/**",
            "/navigation-update/**",
            "/resources/icons/**",
            "/compiled/**",
            "/auth/**",
            "/login",
            "/js/**",
            "/css/**",
            "/images/**"
    };

    @Autowired
    private Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder theJackson2ObjectMapperBuilder;

    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lInterceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lInterceptor.setParamName("lang");
        registry.addInterceptor(lInterceptor).excludePathPatterns(FREE_ACCESS_PATHS);
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/")
                .setCachePeriod(604800)
                .resourceChain(true)
                .addResolver(new VersionResourceResolver()
                        .addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        theJackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.serializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
        theJackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.indentOutput(true).dateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"));
        theJackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.modules(new JodaModule());
        converters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter(theJackson2ObjectMapperBuilder.build()));
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver lCookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        lCookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.UK);
        return lCookieLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource lMessageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        lMessageSource.setBasename("classpath:i18n/messages");
        lMessageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return lMessageSource;
    }

}

@Configuration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder thePasswordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .headers()
                .addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter.XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN))
                .and()
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        "/ws/**",
                        "/navigation-update/**",
                        "/resources/icons/icon.ico",
                        "/compiled/auth.bundle.js",
                        "/auth/*",
                        "/login",
                        "/js/logoutTimer.js",
                        "/css/bootstrap.min.css",
                        "/images/GFLLogo.png",
                        "/images/Login.png")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedPage("/auth/denied")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                .loginPage("/auth/login.html")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/auth/logout.html")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/auth/login.html")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                .maximumSessions(2)
                .expiredUrl("/auth/login.html")
                .and()
                .invalidSessionUrl("/auth/login.html");
    }

    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean())
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(thePasswordEncoder);

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) {
        web.ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/**");
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

Comment: The fact that you have all those annotations flying around is a clear indication it was wrong from the start. Things like `@EnableWebMvc` disable auto configuration for the defaults. That and you are upgrading (and thus skipping) 6 versions with each a migration guide.

Answer (score 0):

- The problem was the file extension of the .ftl templates.

[Spring Boot Freemarker fails from 2.2.0 upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58540560/spring-boot-freemarker-fails-from-2-2-0-upgrade)

- **fixed using spring.freemarker.suffix property**